# log4j2 pattern: Hide source code line if not compiled with debug information

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I use log4j 2.7 in my product. I configured log4j to use a RollingFile appender with the following pattern:

```
%d - %-5p - [%t] - (%C::%M[%L]) - %notEmpty{%marker: }%m%n
```

When I compile it inside the IDE the line number is set. When I use an ant task the line number is not set (because the build artifact **should not** include debug information) and log4j prints out `-1` as line number.

Is it possible to hide the `-1` in brackets when the line number is not set?

Example:

```
LogManager.getLogger().debug("This is a message");
```

the result is

```
2016-11-02 14:22:53,481 - DEBUG - [JavaFX Application Thread] - (Main::start[-1]) - This is a message
```

but it should be

```
2016-11-02 14:22:53,481 - DEBUG - [JavaFX Application Thread] - (Main::start) - This is a message
```